# Why does my system call work in the irb but not in a rake task?

Tags: ruby, rake

I try to run `system "./do_backup.py"` within my rake task, where do_backup.py is a python program in the same directory, but the command fails silently. I can run it using `system "./do_backup.py"`, however.

I called `system "whoami"` from both within my rake task and the IRB, and the users are the same.

EDIT

Here's the rakefile:

```
desc "Back up a file onto S3"
task :backup do
     S3ID = "AKIAJM3NRWxxx"
     S3KEY = "0A5kuzV+E1dkaPjxxx"
     SRCBUCKET = "rose-test-4"
     NUM_BACKUP_BUCKETS = 2

     system "whoami" 
     system "./do_backup.py #{S3ID} #{S3KEY} #{SRCBUCKET} #{NUM_BACKUP_BUCKETS}"
end
```

Comment: `Kernel.system()` works fine from within Rakefiles; my guess is that you changed directories before calling it.  Please post your Rakefile.

Comment: Looks good to me. You're running it from the same directory as the Python script?  What does `system "ls -l ./do_backup.py"` show? What's the return value of the last call to `system()` (the one that launches the Python script)?

Comment: You're right! It was executing the rake task from the root of the rails project, not `lib/tasks`. How do you recommend I cd into `lib/tasks` from the inside the rake task? Of course, `system "cd lib/tasks` doesn't work.

Comment: Using `#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks/do_backup.py` might be easier than messing around with `chdir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this was being run from the wrong directory.  You can change directories with `Dir.chdir()`.  For example:

```
  ...
  Dir.chdir("lib/tasks")
  system "./do_backup.py #{S3ID} #{S3KEY} #{SRCBUCKET} #{NUM_BACKUP_BUCKETS}"
end
```

Of course, as @muistooshort points out, the simpler thing is to just run it from where it is:

```
  system "#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks/do_backup.py #{S3ID} #{S3KEY} #{SRCBUCKET} #{NUM_BACKUP_BUCKETS}"
```

Comment: `chdir("#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks")` might be a better idea.